# How I can specify a value for various elements on Python specially in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I don't know how I can set the same value for different actions in Python.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("...")
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
# You can see I wrote the same value for various things

t1.hideturtle()
t2.hideturtle()
t3.hideturtle()

t1.speed(0)
t2.speed(0)
t3.speed(0)

t1.pu()
t2.pu()
t3.pu()

t1.showturtle()
t2.showturtle()
t3.showturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to write this.

Comment: Theres a few problems with this: You havent defined t3 (t3 = turtle.Turtle()) so your code wont run.
I'm not sure what you mean by "value" Do you mean the "0" in the speed function?
If you mean can you change the speed of all three turtles at once, then you could do them as a loop like the answer below

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to store the turtles in a list, and then loop through the list.  Something of this nature.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("...")
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)

# You could loop this as well, but since you're just beginning...
turtles = []
turtles[0] = turtle.Turtle()
turtles[1] = turtle.Turtle()
turtles[2] = turtle.Turtle()

for t in turtles:
     t.hideturtle()
     t.speed(0)
     t.pu()
     t.showturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

If you didn't need to access the turtles again:

```
# ---
number_of_turtles = 3  # or however many

for i in range(0, number_of_turtles):
     t = turtle.Turtle()
     t.hideturtle()
     t.speed(0)
     t.pu()
     t.showturtle()
# ---
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to configure one turtle as an (implicit or explicit) prototype with all the common features.  Then use `clone()` to create copies of that prototype and then set their individual properties:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.title("...")
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)

t1 = Turtle()
t1.hideturtle()
t1.speed('fastest')
t1.penup()

t2 = t1.clone()
t2.setx(100)

t3 = t1.clone()
t3.sety(100)

t1.showturtle()
t2.showturtle()
t3.showturtle()

screen.mainloop()
```